# Passing two arrays from one method to gather user info from another method C#

Tags: c#

I'm not looking for specific code, rather, I'm looking for information and guidance.  I want to learn but don't really want someone to code it.

I am looking in how to pass two arrays to a different method so they can be filled with user input.  I can't seem to figure this out and I have researched various sites as well as my text and lectures and can't find the required techniques to do this.  I know how to pass one array to a different method for processing (IE getting avg/sum etcetc) but not how to fill two arrays from one seperate method.  Any guidance and information would be greatly appreciated.  This is what I've got so far, or rather, what I'm left with.  I got the other methods fairly done over, just need this part to move onto the debugging phase.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PhoneDial
{
    class Program
    {


        // Get player names and their scores and stores them into array for an unknown number of players up to 100
        static void InputData(string[] nameList, int[]playerScore)
        {
            string userInput;
            int count = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("\nEnter a players name: ");
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userInput != "Q" && userInput != "q")
                {
                    nameList[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                    ++count;

                }
                else break;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter {0}'s score:", userInput);
                playerScore[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            } while (userInput != "Q" && userInput != "q");


        }

        //Declare variables for number of players and average score and two arrays of size 100 (one for names, one for respective scores
        //Calls functions in sequence, passing necessary parameters by reference
        //InputData(), passing arrays and number of players variable by reference
        //DisplayPlayerData(), passing arrays and number of players by reference
        //CalculateAverageScore(), passing arrays and number of players by reference. Store returned value in avg variable
        //DisplayBelowAverage(), passing arrays and number of players variable by reference, passing average variable by value
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] nameList = new string[100];
            int[] playerScore = new int[100];
            int count = 0, avg = 0;

            InputData(nameList, playerScore);


        }
```

Comment: How about creating a class that hold two arrays? Then you can pass this around all you like...

Comment: Maybe instead of `static void InputData(ref string name, ref int score)` you should use `static void InputData(string[] name, int[] score, ref int numberOfPlayers)`

Comment: Would creating a class remove it out of main()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but from what I understand, to declare an array in a method and pass to another method to be filled, you just need:

```
public void MethodA()
{
    string[] stringArray = new string[100];

    MethodB(stringArray);
}

public void MethodB(string[] stringArray)
{
    // Fill the array
    stringArray[0] = "Hello";

    // ...
}
```

If, however, you wish to pass some variable reference to a method to then have that method create the array *and* fill it, you will want to use the `ref` keyword (as you have with standard variables) on an array variable. Like so:

```
public void MethodA()
{
    string[] stringArray;

    MethodB(ref stringArray);

    // Array is now created and filled
}

public void MethodB(ref string[] stringArray)
{
    // Create the array
    stringArray = new string[100];

    // Fill the array
    stringArray[0] = "Hello";

    // ...
}
```

To do either of these two approaches with *two* arrays is the same, but with an added parameter. i.e.:

```
public void MethodB(string[] array1, int[] array2) { }

public void MethodB(ref string[] array1, ref int[] array2) { }
```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks a ton.  I think this is what I was looking for.  I'll try it out when I get home.

Comment: I updated the code to show your first method, would that be the correct way?  Also, what is the benefit or purpose of doing one of your methods over the other?  The second one changes the values of the Arrays, I think, right?

Comment: Using either approach you can change the values stored in the array. However, the second approach (the one using the [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.71).aspx) keyword) passes the arrays by reference. This means you are able to initialize the variable as you have a reference to it, rather than just the value.

Answer (score 3):

Use Dictionary instead of array.

```
Dictionary<string, int> Results = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x525za90%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: We haven't covered dictionaries in class yet.  the comments in the code are the directions that we have to follow.   :(

Answer (score 1):

You can make the variables nameList and playerScore global by putting them under the class Program{ (dont forget to make the variables static and make lists of them).

then in your InputData use the .add method to add aditional values to the two variables.

Maybe it is also a good idea to use a dictionary instead of two arrays.

I hope this helped

Comment: I'm afraid neither method is right for me.  the commments in the code are the directions for the lab project.  We haven't covered dictionaries yet and if I'm not mistaken, doesn't making them global take them out of Main()?